# How do I solve "-307" error on ZKTeco SDK?

Tags: access-control, fingerprint, biometrics, time-and-attendance, zkteco

Hello everyone and thanks for reading this problem.

I have a solution in C# using the zkemkeeper dll to get the records from some access control devices. When I "ping" them, there isn't any problem, but when I try to connect to them (Using my solution or the standalone demo to get attendance) I get the "-307" error with the "Unable to connect message". That's not very clear and I would really aprecciate if someone can explain what this error is (please!!!!). I would really like to understand these errors myself, so, where can I find all the definition of these errors?

In short:

1.- What is the problem regarding the "-307" error?
2.- Is there any place where all these errors are documented?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attention
The dwErrorCode parameter specifies the error code. The values are described as follows:

1. During connection, the following error codes may be returned:
   0 Connected successfully
   -1 Failed to invoke the interface
   -2 Failed to initialize
   -3 Failed to initialize parameters
   -5 Data mode read error
   -6 Wrong password
   -7 Reply error
   -8 Receive timeout
   -307 Connection timeout
   In invoking other interfaces, the following error codes may be returned:
   -201 Device is busy
   -199 New Mode
   -103 device send back error of face version error
   -102 face template version error, like 8.0 face template send to 7.0 device
   -101 malloc memory failed
   -100 Not supported or the data does not exist
   -10 The length of transmitted data is incorrect
   -5 Data already exists
   -4 Insufficient space
   -3 Wrong size
   -2 File read/write error
   -1 The SDK is not initialized and needs to be reconnected
   0 Data not found or duplicate data
   1 Correct operation
   4 Parameter error
   101 Buffer allocation error
   102 repeat invoking
2. Underlying error codes:
   -12001 Socket creation timeout (connection timeout)
   -12002 Insufficient memory
   -12003 Wrong Socket version
   -12004 Not TCP protocol
   -12005 Waiting timeout
   -12006 Data transmission timeout
   -12007 Data reading timeout
   -12008 Failed to read Socket
   -13009 Waiting event error
   -13010 Exceeded retry attempts
   -13011 Wrong reply ID
   -13012 Checksum error
   -13013 Waiting event timeout
   -13014 DIRTY_DATA
   -13015 Buffer size too small
   -13016 Wrong data length
   -13017 Invalid data read1
   -13018 Invalid data read2
   -13019 Invalid data read3
   -13020 Data loss
   -13021 Memory initialization error
   -15001 Invoking return value of status key issued by SetShortkey interface repeatedly
   -15002 Invoking return value of description issued by SetShortkey interface repeatedly
   -15003 The two level menu is not opened in the device, and the data need not be issued
3. getdevicedata and setdevicedata invocation error codes
   -15100 Error occurs in obtaining table structure
   -15101 The condition field does not exist in the table structure
   -15102 Inconsistency in the total number of fields
   -15103 Inconsistency in sorting fields
   -15104 Memory allocation error
   -15105 Data parsing error
   -15106 Data overflow as the transmitted data exceeds 4M
   -15108 Invalid options
   -15113 Data parsing error: table ID not found
   -15114 A data exception is returned as the number of fields is smaller than or equal to 0
   -15115 A data exception is returned as the total number of table fields is inconsistent with the
   total number of fields of the data
4. Firmware error codes:
   2000 Return OK to execute
   -2001 Return Fail to execute command
   -2002 Return Data
   -2003 Regstered event occorred
   -2004 Return REPEAT Command
   -2005 Return UNAUTH Command
   0xffff Return Unknown Command
   -4999 Device parameter read error
   -4998 Device parameter write error
   -4997 The length of the data sent by the software to the device is incorrect
   228
   229
   -4996 A parameter error exists in the data sent by the software to the device
   -4995 Failed to add data to the database
   -4994 Failed to update the database
   -4993 Failed to read data from the database
   -4992 Failed to delete data in the database
   -4991 Data not found in the database
   -4990 The data amount in the database reaches the limit
   -4989 Failed to allocate memory to a session
   -4988 Insufficient space in the memory allocated to a session
   -4987 The memory allocated to a session overflows
   -4986 File does not exist
   -4985 File read failure
   -4984 File write failure
   -4983 Failed to calculate the hash value
   -4982 Failed to allocate memory
   Note
   This interface is applicable to the new architecture firmware.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8pF1.png)

maybe you should check your device, you can ping them

Comment: Thanks in advance!! Do you know where I can get all the errors or where did you get that piece of documentation from?

Comment: your welcome, you can see my new answer below